# Is it possible that I can play Minecraft (Xbox disk) on my Windows 8 PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, pc

I want to play Minecraft on PC, but my parents said that they won't buy me it since I have it on Xbox.

My question is can I download Minecraft onto my PC and can I go into my Xbox account and play it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. To play Minecraft on your PC, you would need to purchase the Java or Bedrock edition for the PC platform. You can do that [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/get-minecraft). I wish you luck in convincing your parents.